# A quote by Lev Landau about prime numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, soft-question, ho.history-overview

I was talking with a student of mine about Goldbach's conjecture, and a certain point he asked why this apparently simple statement is so difficult to prove.

Half-joking, I answered "well, because *prime numbers are made to be multiplied, not added*", explaining that it is a well-known quote by Lev Landau, or at least this is what a Google research shows (see for instance  [here](http://www.azquotes.com/quote/1359041)).

However, I was unable to find any authoritative source supporting this attribution.  This led me to ask what follows:

> **Q.** Is this quote really by Landau? If so, what is the original source? Is it written in some of his papers, or is there some historical account supporting this credit?

Comment: Probably exactly the same Google research you did turns this up in an [opinion piece by Arnol'd](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03024363):  p. 8, "'Why *add* prime numbers?' marvelled the great physicist Lev Landau.  'Prime numbers are made to be multiplied, not added!'"  Of course this doesn't answer the question, but maybe suggests an answer like "he said it to Arnol'd"?

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, it would be better to ask that here: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, Arnold's statement seems not very far away from the answer I gave to my student: did Landau *really* said this to Arnold, or Arnold just used the sentence as a "well-known" Landau quote? Secondly, I agree that asking on the forum of history of science could be an option, however there is still a tag "history" on MO. And it is still used, as far as I can see.

Comment: How to prove that anyone said anything in the past? If I were next to Landau when he said that, and wrote somewhere that he said that, then that could classify as a proof (under certain assumptions) that he said that. Maybe Landau took that sentence about primes from some of his students, is then that statement his or of that student?

Comment: My point is that if there is no precise way to be sure that the statement is due to Landau, then it should be considered apocryphal. It happens that I teach number theory, and I like to be precise in the quotes, wherever possible. At any rate, are we sure that Landau never *wrote* this?

Comment: I believe you all of that. Do you love this quote: https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/ralph_waldo_emerson_107450

Comment: Landau said this not to Arnol'd but to Vinogradov, or at least on the occasion of Vinogradov's work on the Goldbach conjecture, in the 1930s, when Arnold was not old enough to have a conversation on the subject.

Comment: @IgorRivin: thanks for the information! Is there any historical source for this (some mention in Vinogradov's papers, for instance)?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi I will try to find the source, this is folklore in some circles...

Comment: @IgorRivin I believe it was Abraham Lincoln who said that quotes on the web are often misattributed

Comment: @WillJagy Web? I knew this before there was a web.

Comment: @Will: We all remember how George W Ashington misunderstimated the powers of the dark WEB by looking deep into his soul

Comment: @VictorProtsak one of the Reacher books by Lee Child, called Make Me, (a thriller) makes a good presentation of the dark web.. hmm, I was going to link the wikipedia article but it is full of spoilers.

Comment: @IgorRivin for the record, I thought it was a bad idea when Arpanet expanded beyond military and universities to, eventually, the general public.

Comment: Are you sure it was Lev and not Edmund the mathematician? The webpage you are pointing doesn’t seem very authoritative.

Comment: For example most physicists think the big/little-O notation is due to Lev

Comment: @Icv: I agree with you. The point is that I cannot find *any* authoritative source.

Comment: @WillJagy You and me both.

Comment: @lcv Absolutely Lev.

Comment: I remember thinking the same thing about summing exponents, the first time I encountered the Fourier transform. That was some time ago. I also remember that when discussing the history of the above quote with Terry Tao, he mentioned that he likes to subtract primes. That was much later, but still some years ago...